# Xcode - Google Maps API waypoints is not working

Tags: xcode, google-maps

When I use this url request :

```
NSString* apiUrlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?output=dragdir&saddr=%@&daddr=%@&waypoints=37.786894,-122.412004",saddr,daddr];
```

the route returned is not crossing the waypoint. you can see the function I used, here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523084

so what's the problem ?